# What are the grammatical rules for using filler words in Japanese(e.g. ええと, なんか, あの, and so on)?

Tags: grammar

I found a bit interesting bits on them through some research, but nothing about what the grammatical rules are for using them all. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there aren't any rules, they serve as breaks in a conversation (usu. for the speaker as they are thinking) so if there were rules that would kind of defeat their purpose.  Think of "um" or "uh" in English, are there *rules* for that?

Comment: Fair enough. What are some of the more commonly used filler words in Japanese, though?

Comment: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1171709961

Comment: You've got most of them down :P, I can't think of anything else right now

Answer (score 3):

Fillers are [speech disfluency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_disfluency). It's part of speech but not grammar.  Use them to fill voids in speech just like English speakers use "Um..", "well..", "like.."